# How I should dispatch the action to fetch the data using react components and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am fetching data using axios and then map state to props with redux but I have a problem. If I dispatch the action in `componentDidUpdate()` the action execute indefinitely and if I used the `constructor(props)` I get undefined value for `props` I tried also `componentDidMount` but I get undefined value for probs. Is there a way to dispatch the action **using react components** ?

I get the correct data from `state` in the second render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { getUserPosts } from '../../actions'

class UserPosts extends Component {

    //UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {

    //}
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }


    componentDidUpdate() {
        //this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(this.props.user_reducer.login?.user._id));
    }

    showUserPosts = (user) => (

        Array.isArray(user.userPosts) ?
          user.userPosts.map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                <td>{i}</td>
                <td>author</td>
                <td>date</td>
                </tr>    

          ))
        : null    

    )

    render() {
        let user = this.props.user_reducer;
        //console.log(user.userPosts);
        return (
            <div>
               <div className="user_posts">
                   <h4>Your reviews:</h4>
                   <table>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Author</th>
                               <th>Date</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           {this.showUserPosts(user)}
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    //console.log(state);
    return {
        user_reducer: state.user_reducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserPosts)
```

action:

```
export function getUserPosts(userId) {
    const req = axios.get(`/api/user_posts?user=${userId}`)
                .then(res => res.data);

    return {
        type: 'GET_USER_POSTS',
        payload: req
    }
}
```

reducer:

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'USER_LOGIN':
            return {...state, login: action.payload}
        case 'USER_AUTH':
            return {...state, login: action.payload}
        case 'GET_USER_POSTS':
            return {...state, userPosts: action.payload}
        default: return state; 
    }
}
```

Comment: did you used dispatcher in action.js

Comment: no I use it in the component above

Comment: Can we see your store/reducer setup? Also, did you wrap your application in Provider?

Comment: Can you get the user id from anywhere else like router params? Otherwise maybe restructure things to not pass an id and have the store request the user specific data based on a user id set via a previous dispatch in the background then map state to props to this new property such as userDetail.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes I get the user id as a parameter

Comment: I don't mean from the store, but from other sources. Are you using react-router-dom or something like that where you can get the `_id` from the url params for example? The `_id` property you are is nested very deeply. It may not be available until after the component has mounted.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky it was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place to dispatch an action is in componentDidMount. However since your data fetch is async, you must maintain a loading state in your reducer till your data is fetched

```
export default function(state = {isPostLoading: true}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'USER_LOGIN':
            return {...state, login: action.payload}
        case 'USER_AUTH':
            return {...state, login: action.payload}
        case 'GET_USER_POSTS':
            return {...state, userPosts: action.payload, isPostLoading: false}
        default: return state; 
    }
}
```

---

```
class UserPosts extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
       this.props.dispatch(
           getUserPosts(this.props.user_reducer.login?.user._id) 
      );
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if(this.props.user_reducer.login?.user._id !== prevProps.user_reducer.login?.user._id) {
          this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(this.props.user_reducer.login?.user._id));
       }
    }

    showUserPosts = (user) => (

        Array.isArray(user.userPosts) ?
          user.userPosts.map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                <td>{i}</td>
                <td>author</td>
                <td>date</td>
                </tr>    

          ))
        : null    

    )

    render() {
        let user = this.props.user_reducer;
        if(user.isPostLoading) {
            return <div>Loading....</div>
        }
        return (
            <div>
               <div className="user_posts">
                   <h4>Your reviews:</h4>
                   <table>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Author</th>
                               <th>Date</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           {this.showUserPosts(user)}
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        user_reducer: state.user_reducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserPosts)
```

Comment: Thanks but first render I dont get the data, I get it in second render. `user_reducer` prop in `componentDidMount` is empty . old code was using `componentWillMount` which not used now

Comment: Is the login value true on initial render

Comment: yes the login value was false, it seems you know now I am following a tutorials :) it work now thanks

Comment: Seems like you would need to use of combination of componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate since your login was false

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: Thanks alot, can you explain please what is the effect of login true or false ? I have this router `<Route path="/user/user-reviews" exact component={Auth(UserPosts, true)}/>`

Comment: never mind it is because of this `<ComposedClass {...this.props} user={this.props.user_reducer}/>`